# How do I add custom tables to App for Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365-sales, dynamics365-app-outlook

I already tried asking this in the [Microsoft Dynamics forum](https://community.dynamics.com/365/f/dynamics-365-general-forum/458011/trouble-customizing-app-for-outlook).

I have deployed the [App for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/outlook-app/overview). I have added three custom tables (entities). These now show up in [Quick Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/outlook-app/add-a-custom-entity-to-quick-create) and the [Regarding lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/outlook-app/search-on-custom-field-regarding-lookup).

I have also removed the Contact, Lead, and Account tables. But when I click the Add button, the three options are "Add as Contact" and so on.

When I click on an email that is already saved in Dynamics 365 Sales Enterprise, the Recipient Picker says "Unknown Recipient" (see image below). How can I get the Recipient picker to include the custom tables that I've added?

I've tried refreshing the app, redeploying, and running the [App for Outlook checker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/outlook-app/diagnostic-checker).

App for Outlook is using Exchange server-side synchronization.

Thanks,
Shane.

[image: App for Outlook]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know and I read, you cannot set custom entity for Recepient. It can only be Account, contact or lead. But you can set Regarding for custom entity and track email communication.